# Rewrite Cocos2d (objective-c) on Coco2d-x (c + +)

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, translate

Please help, I can not rewrite this code to `objective-c` on `C++`
   `cocos2d` (`objective-c`):

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [_touches unionSet:touches];
    }

    - (void) ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [_touches minusSet:touches];
    }

    - (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [_touches minusSet:touches];
    }

    - (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        for (UITouch * touch in touches)
        {
            [self pinchZoomWithMovedTouch:touch];
        }
    }

    - (void) pinchZoomWithMovedTouch: (UITouch *) movedTouch
    {
        CGFloat minDistSqr = CGFLOAT_MAX;
        UITouch * nearestTouch = nil;
        UIView * mainView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
        CGPoint newLocation = [movedTouch locationInView:mainView];
        for (UITouch * touch in _touches)
        {
            if (touch != movedTouch)
            {
                CGFloat distSqr = sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints([touch locationInView:mainView],newLocation);
                if (distSqr < minDistSqr)
                {
                    minDistSqr = distSqr;
                    nearestTouch = touch;
                }
            }
        }
        if (nearestTouch)
        {
            CGFloat prevDistSqr = sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints([nearestTouch locationInView:mainView],
                                                             [movedTouch previousLocationInView:mainView]);
            CGFloat pinchDiff = sqrtf(minDistSqr) - sqrtf(prevDistSqr);
            scal1+= pinchDiff * kPinchZoomCoeff;
            if (scal1>=1 &&(scal1<=3)) {
                            self.scale += pinchDiff * kPinchZoomCoeff; // kPinchZoomCoeff is constant = 1.0 / 200.0f Adjust it for your needs
                scal1=self.scale;
            }

            scal1=self.scale;
            NSLog(@"Scale   %f",self.scale);
            }
    }

    CGFloat sqrOfDistanceBetweenPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
    {
        CGPoint diff = ccpSub(p1, p2);
        return diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y;
    }
```

I just started learning cocos2d-x and therefore difficult to rewrite)
I would be very grateful if someone can help rewrite this code to cocos2d-x

Comment: What cocos2d-x version are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: cocos2d-x-2.2.1
 for example do not quite understand how to write it here: [_touches unionSet: touches];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCSet in cocos2d-x don't have methods to join two sets or remove objects from one set in another. You can use touch delegate instead of standard delegate and use methods:

```
 virtual bool ccTouchBegan (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual bool ccTouchMoved (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchEnded (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

Then you can add or remove every single touch from or to _touches.

If you want use touch delegate you must override registerWithTouchDispatcher();

```
void Strona::registerWithTouchDispatcher() {
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, this->getTouchPriority(), true);
}
```

Or you can simply iterate in every touch in touches from ccTouchesBegan and add every touch from touches to _touches.